# Understanding partition size modification

Tags: linux, partitioning, disk-space

I'm trying to understand the relation between block size, and partition siz.

Partition size needs to be an integer multiple of a block, so if the page size is 4KB, and each block has 64 pages, the block size == 4KB*64 = 256 KB, but what about the partition size?

If the pagesize is 4KB, is becomes essential to take 256 as a block size?

Not sure if this is a standard but here's the [link to an XML file](https://e-mailky.github.io/2018-12-14-ipq40xx-mtd)
where you specify the partition name and the size (where size is broken down into `size_kb` and `pad_kb`.

So if you were to set the partition size to 50M, how would you go about making changes to this XML file? Would you do `50 * 1024KB = 51200 KB` where `size_kb = 50176` and `pad_kb = 1024` which is the rest of the space, and why?

Comment: Do you have more context – this terminology and question looks like it's very specific to raw NAND flash? (The "block" in particular is unusual for me, since in PCs it is the _smallest_ logical unit of storage, and I would have thought pages would be made out of blocks and not the other way around.)

Comment: yes it's in the context of a NAND flash. Sorry this is still new to me and i'm trying to understand it